# Can you hook up a horse to a wagon and drive it in Red Dead Redemption 2?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

Can you hook up a horse to a wagon to drive it?

For example, in Beechers Hope, there is a wagon with no horses. Are you able to hook one up to drive it?

Answer (score 8):

No there is no ability to hook a horse to a wagon.